# What are some disadvantages of having exposed pins on a connector?

Tags: lightning

For example, the Apple Lightning connector has exposed pins. What are some disadvantages of exposed pins besides corrosion (and shorting out the power supply when not in use, which shouldn't be a problem if the power is only turned on when plugged in)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the cable supplies power at all times on exposed pins that are near each other, that probably will not end well. (Short circuits, etc if the host does not appropriately current limit). An additional ESD risk is also present.

Also, exposed pins are at a higher risk of damage -- bending, breaking-off, etc. If you don't notice, and try to make a damaged connector to its mating plug/receptacle, chances are that you'll damage the plug / receptacle as well.

Comment: +1. In addition, there is a risk of shock in case the connector was coming from a ac to DC converter and something went wrong inside the converter. For this reason, usually sources are female with hidden metal parts and recipients are male with exposed pins in ac - [Socket and plug for example](http://secrets-of-self-sufficiency.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/how-to-install-a-plug-socket-outlet.jpg)